# Another web service call inside ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web-services

I have an angular application which I need to call web services. I have to call two different url to get data.
In my first url is like ==> 
**abc.com/student/3** this is the list of student. and another URL is 
**abc.com/parent/idofStudent3**  when I pass student id of 3 in the second URL I need to get parent first name from the second URL.

I am able to retrieve the first URL data but I am unable to retrieve second URL data by passing first record data in **ng-repeat**. Could you please help me how to retrieve parent name in the web page?

Html Page

```
<h1 ng-repeat="x in myWelcome">
{{x.firstname}} || {{x.parentId}} </h1>
```

Here instead of displaying **parentid** I need to call another web service to display parent name by passing **parentId** as a parameter. how to call another web service here?

```
<script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
        $http.get("abc.com/student/3")
            .then(function(response) {
                $scope.myWelcome = response.data;
            });
    });
</script>
```

==> First webservice response is like :

```
   {
    "student":[
    {
         "name":"john",
          "parentId": 12,
    "address":"NYC"
},

    {
         "name":"Rohi",
          "parentId": 14,
    "address":"NJ"
},
 ]
 }
```

==> second webservice response is like this when parentID=12:

```
{
"firstName": "Sr. John",

}
======> when parentIS 14
{
"firstName": "Sr. Rohi",

}


-------------------------
firstname || parentName
-------------------------
John      ||  Sr. John
Rohi      ||   Sr. Rohi
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you are searching for `Parent details` in the wrong scope object; `myWelcome` object is containing data from first service call, which returned `list of student` details only.

You can define a new scope object and bind data to it from second service call which will contain parent details; you can then use that object in `ng-repeat`.

Comment: I need to return the second webservice data by passing first web service data a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
         $scope.myWelcome = []
        $http.get("abc.com/student/3")
            .then(function(response) {
                $scope.StudentData = response.data;
          if($scope.StudentData){
                  $scope.myWelcome.push($scope.StudentData)
                  $http.get("abc.com/parent/$scope.StudentData.studentId")
                     .then(function(response) {
                       $scope.parentData = response.data;
                        $scope.myWelcome.push($scope.parentData)

            });
          }
        });
    });
</script>
```

I guess this might help you

Comment: I updated my json response of first web service . where the response of first web service is a list of student. Thank you